# How can I manage my Instagram account from Python?

Tags: python, logging, token, instagram

I'm trying to do a Python program to follow some users based on the hastags they use on their posts. I know about the instagram package for Python, but there are a few things I don't understand about it.

Do I need a token for writing this program? If so, what exacly is a token? And when I run the get-token function it asks me to write the redirect URL, the requested scope, and the "Paste in code in query string after redirect: ", and I have no idea of that is this.

Thank you, JM

Comment: http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand [OAuth 2](https://www.google.com/search?q=OAuth+2+tutorial) in order to appreciate what a token really means. But in essence the redirect URL is the place to where Instagram sends a user who wants to use your app after he approves of it. You will need to *host* your application. ([How to do this?](https://www.google.com/q=host+python+apps)). Also Instagram has a page that helps developers get started [here](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/).

Once you are done with the above steps and have the token, you can do something like this,

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
# Subscribe to all media tagged with 'fox'
api.create_subscription(object='tag', object_id='fox', aspect='media', callback_url='http://example.com/hook/instagram')
```